# How to enable dates only between current date and previous 7 days on DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Following pic is a web date picker. 
There, only **between current date and previous 7 days** are able to be selected.

[image]

I've to do this at Android using `DatePickerDialog`. I implemented `DatePickerDialog` on my `EditText`'s `OnClickListener` as an example [here](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-datepickerdialog-on-edittext-click-event/). 
The question is how to make user could not select out of that range? Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set minimum and maximum date.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
Date result = cal.getTime();
mDatePicker.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
mDatePicker.setMinDate(result.getTime());
```

Comment: great, that's what i need. You da real MVP.

Comment: Please accept as correct, if it was really helpful :)

Comment: second line didn't work dude, it should be mDatePicker.setMinDate(newCalendar.get(cal.MILLISECOND));

Comment: But you wanna set minimum date 7 days ago?

Comment: yap, result.getTime() is not a correct parameter type. Both setMaxDate and setMinDate methods' parameter should be milliseconds. That's why I juz convert you "cal" to millisecond. :)

Comment: Okay, You can go through that way too. :)

Comment: Great effort dude...This is really helpful to me